# delphi - setting up database connection without connected to it

Tags: oracle, delphi-7, zeos

So, I am currently doing project for my branch office. I was making it there but right now I am away from office. I have set db connection with zeos which connected to local server of branch office that has database in it. However, right now I need to correct some stuffs but since I am away I cannot be connected to branch office's server which have the db.
in my zeos connection I set its properties (no coding, just set it directly from its properties):

```
database name : xxx
host name : ((ip server))
```

when I fix something, connection turned to false (obviously). can I set this to true in coding so when I sent this app over this app can be used in branch office?
thanks!

Comment: Any property you set in the Object Inspector can also be set in code. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: so basically I just need to code zconnection1.connect on form create? @KenWhite problem is when I fix code, db connection turned false because I am now not connected to local server however i wanted this .exe file to be sent to branch office so that it can be used, how to set it so it turned true when connected to local server?

Comment: Yes, or in the OnCreate of your data module. It's still unclear what you're asking. You add code to set the properties at runtime, just like you would in the Object Inspector. Your issue is going to be *How do I know if I'm running on the local server or at the branch office?*, and we can't answer that for you. *Any property you set in the Object Inspector can be set in code* is the answer, until you can describe a **specific problem** you're having doing so.